# Linear algebra: Finding cosine between vectors given inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

I've come across a question that wants me to find the cosine of the angle between two vectors within an inner product space. The issue is, the vectors are defined as being $x$ and $x+1$.

The inner product space: $$\langle p , q\rangle = \int_0^1 p(x)q(x) \,dx$$

I assume I use $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\langle p,q\rangle}{\|p\| \|q\|} $$ but I am unable to find the norms for $p$ and $q$.

I found that $\langle p , q \rangle = 5/6$

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For example:

$$||x+1||^2=\int\limits_0^1 (x+1)^2dx=\left.\frac13(x+1)^3\right|_0^1=\frac13(8-1)=\frac73$$

BTW, I get $\;\theta=19.11^\circ\;$

Comment: Thank you for your help. This uses <p,p> to get ||p||^2, and from there, you just take the sqrt to find ||p||, right? 

Thank you heaps for your help! I'll take another look and see what I can do

Comment: Yes! I figured it out - Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Think about this: what is $\langle p,p\rangle$?

If that doesn't get you on track, consider this: for a normal spatial vector, how does $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}$ relate to the norm (a.k.a. magnitude a.k.a. length) of the vector $\vec{x}$?